# How to Update Deployed React App on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, web-deployment, github-pages

recently I have deployed my first React App on GitHub Pages
***https://karan-dhingra.github.io/lct/***

Now I updated react app and my changes are not reflected on GitHub Pages. But everything was working well on Localhost. So, please guide me on how can I update my deployed React App on GitHub Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just we need to run 3-4 commands

`git init`

`git remote ****************.git` [ Here we will add our repository link ending with.git you will found it in the code option in your repo.

`npm run deploy` [Make sure you have installed gh pages first]

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Here you write message while committing, you can write anything here"`

`git push origin master`

So, with using these commands everything will work well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save the code in the IDE. after saving check with "git status" command and commit & push to git repo and the changes will be reflected

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the lines below have helped. My app is deployed via **gh-pages**:

```
git add .
git commit -m '...'
npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that You have your app running through **github gh-pages** and You made some changes in your app and you want them to reflect in your **gh-pages**.
You can achieve in following two step

1. Make sure you are in your app folder in terminal and no service are related to your app
2. Just run deploy code `npm run deploy`

Enjoy you are good to go.